# apply counter for multiple list elements Jquery

Tags: jquery

The counter works fine for the first list element. However, it does not do anything for the other ones.

Here is my jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/t0ygauo6/1/

```
$('#signatures').data('count', 0);
    $('#sign').click(function () {
      $('#signatures').html(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
          count = $this.data('count') + 1;

        $this.data('count', count);
        return count;
    });
});

$('#signatures').data('count', 0);
 $('#unsign').click(function () {
   $('#signatures').html(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            count = $this.data('count') - 1;

        $this.data('count', count);
        return count;
    });
});
```

Comment: IDs must be unique.  Use classes and relative DOM navigation instead.

Comment: How would you go about the relative DOM navigation?

Comment: Start here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/